# The difference between 3 pronged and 2 pronged power supplies

Tags: power-supply

I'm just wondering what's the difference between a simple power supply with a ground prong and one without. I'm talking about those little DC power supplies with barrel plugs you can easy find on any small appliances. As far as I know a barrel plug has two contacts: one positive and one negative. What's the role of the third ground prong on the AC side for those have it? I hope I'm not mistaken but a small DC power supply like that use floating voltage right? With all plastic construction I don't think it can do much in terms of safety.

Actually I took two PS and toyed with it. One is relatively higher quality with a 3 pronged IEC C13/C14 plug. The other one has a cheapo 2 pronged design. I measured the DC voltage (with a multimeter) between the "wall-socket ground" and the sleeve of the barrel plug. The 3 pronged one resulted a 0 V, while the 2 pronged one showed a fluctuating ~300 mV potential difference. So does that mean the 3 pronged power supply has the negative terminal actually grounded? If it is what's the pros and cons of doing that?

I'll greatly appreciate any input! Thank you!

Comment: Redo your measurements: (1) Unplug the power supplies. (2) Switch your meter to resistance. (3) Measure from earth pin to barrel jack.

Comment: @Transistor The resistance is <1 Ohm. And the meter showed positive in continuity test. So can I deduce the sleeve is grounded?

Comment: Do they both have a "square within square" symbol on them?

Comment: fyi, an example of a small appliance is a toaster or a blender. i think that you mean a `small electronic device`

Comment: measure AC voltage when dealing with power outlets.  ... the sleeve could be the positive terminal. ... measuring only one is doing only 1/2 the test, which means that you do not have enough information that can be used to compare the two power adapters.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Only the 2 pronged one has that symbol. That's a double insulation symbol right?

Comment: @jsotola The sleeves are the negative terminals. It was marked on the power supplies.

Comment: @Den it is indeed the symbol for double insulation

Comment: @Den, makes no difference. you still made only 1/2 the measurements that you should have done. always measure at all the terminals, you may get a nasty surprise if you don't.

Comment: if the negative terminal is grounded, that means you can't series it with another adapter to sum the voltage; not a huge loss for 99% of us. fwiw, i've noticed that new wall worts >2.0A tend to have a ground prong, <2A don't. some products want an earth ground for various reasons, radios for example, and a grounded negative can provide that.

Answer (score 0):

Grounding the output is a cheap and effective way to reduce electromagnetic interferance. but your equipment is then succeptable to ground loops.

Y capacitors are another way but they produce barely preceptable electric shocks. (rub the plug lightly on your external ear and you can hear the electric current)